# What is the best way to synch an outdated git directory to a remote?

Tags: git, github

I keep my vim configuration files on github to keep them synched across multiple machines. Once in a while I use a machine I haven't used in a while and the vim files are way out of synch. If I simply

```
git pull
```

from remote the directory becomes messy since old files (or renamed files) not present anymore in the official remote stay put. So what I typically do is to delete everything and git clone from scratch.

Is that the best approach? Ideally I would like to have a command

```
git xxx
```

which delete/replace everything making a perfect replica of the remote

Comment: When merging, Git will remove files that were removed from the branch you're merging from. It won't touch any files that it has never seen before, though. So maybe your directory _remains_ messy rather than _becomes_ messy?

Comment: @Thomas I see what you say, but the point is that after I get back to a machine I haven't used in a long time I don't want to spend time understanding what I did with that directory, I just want to synch it to my "official" state on the remote

Comment: I see, so there are changes that are not committed. Answer coming up... :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
git fetch origin
git reset --hard origin/master
```

Where `origin` is the remote, and `master` is the remote branch you want to your local working copy to be in sync with. Note that these commands replace any local files (including changes) with the remote state. That means that there will be no merge conflicts. It mimics your delete-and-reclone workflow.

Answer (score 1):

`git pull` will merge in the changes from upstream. Then type `git reset --hard` to revert all modified files to their version as present in HEAD.

There is some risk of merge conflicts. Alexander's answer avoids those.

This will not remove any files that are unknown to Git. For that, shout `git clean`.